# facebook login issue with parse on android

Tags: android

i am using parse sdk 1.4.2

ParseFacebookUtils.initialize("xxxxxxx");

```
ParseFacebookUtils.logIn(this, new LogInCallback() {
    @Override
    public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException err) {
        if (user == null) {

        }
    }
});
```

but while loging in the android facebook app shows an error message. "the page you requested cannot be displayed right now.i may be temporarly unavailable.the link you clicked on may be broken or expired, or you may not have permission to view this page. and while returnig to done method 'user' is null and exception is 'com.parse.ParseException: com.facebook.FacebookOperationCanceledException: Operation canceled' what did i miss here.? i checked the app_id and other settings. its correct. did i miss anything. i run a sample from facebook sdk. it also shows the same error from facebook app. can anybody help me. thank u.